# Reactでyarn startしたらTypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefinedが発生した

Tags: reactjs, react-jsx

Reactでコードを書いた際に `yarn start` を十個すると、以下のエラーが発生しました。
どこが間違っているのでしょうか。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

**コード:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import NewsArticles from "./components/NewsArticles";
import "./App.css";

const url =
  "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=jp&category=technology&apiKey=APIKEY";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const resp = await fetch(url);
      const result = await resp.json();
      setData(result);
      console.log(data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [data]);

  if (data) {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Welcome News App</h1>

        {
         data.articles.map((news) => {
          return <NewsArticles key={news.url} news={news} />
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Sorry no data received</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

明らかな間違いは、useStateの初期化時に`articles`が指定されていません。

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({ articles: [] });
```

次に、fetchのレスポンスが必ずしも`{ aritcles: [] }`を返してくると信頼できないので、

```js
setData(result);
```

で`articles`を欠落させる可能性があります。したがって、次のように書くと良いと思います。

```js
(data.articles || []).map((news) => {
  return <NewsArticles key={news.url} news={news} />
})
```

Comment: 回答者さんのコードを見まして, yarn startしましたら無事Newsが表示されました 。本当にありがとうございます。